# Passing Table and Column as method parameters

Tags: database, vb.net, linq

I am working on a VB.Net app that is connecting to a database with LINQ.  Right now I am creating search fields for different parts of the database which have autocomplete text boxes, where I want the `AutoCompleteSource` to be specific fields in a table.

For example, the text box for the Part Number search would have all of the data from the `Part_Number` field in my `Parts` database.

I am wondering if there is a way to implement a method where I can write a simple query like: `From t in tbl Select field` where both `tbl` and `field` are parameters for the method for the Table and Field respectively.

I've tried programming a query like my small example above, and while the `From t In tbl` part does not initially present me with errors, `Select field` gives me the error:

```
Range variable 'field'hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression.
```

Comment: Since different `tbl` and `field` will have different types, what type do you think the result and parameters will be?

Comment: @NetMage I want to grab the data from a specific column on a specific table, and then store it in an `AutoCompleteSource` variable, for it to be used as the AutoCompleteSource for whatever textbox I am attempting to grab the data for.

Comment: That is good information to add to your question, but doesn't answer mine.

Comment: @NetMage I am not sure what information you're looking for?

Comment: Imaging you are writing the method. Try to write the method signature (return type, method name, parameter types) for this method you want.

Comment: @NetMage Alright, this is what I tested (but does not work): 
`Function GetColumnFromTable(field As String, table As String) As AutoCompleteSource`

Comment: So, `AutoCompleteSource` is a `Type`, right? What is the definition of the `AutoCompleteSource` type?